# Why does `cat` list files instead of content of file here?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, glob

I tried to do something tricky today with bash scripting, which made me question my knowledge of bash scripting.

I have the following script called `get_ftypes.sh`, where the first input argument is a file containing file *globs*:

```
for ftype in `cat $1`
do
    echo "this is ftype $ftype"
done
```

For example, the script would be called like this `get_ftypes.sh file_types`, and `file_types` would contain something like this:

```
*.txt
*.sh
```

I would expect the `echo` to print each line in the file, which in this example would be `*.txt`, `*.sh`, etc.  But, instead it expands the globbing, `*`, and it echos the actual file ***names***, instead of the globb as I would expect.

Any reason for this behavior?  I cannot figure out why.  Thank you.

Comment: This is called glob expansion. try `"\`cat $1\`"`, or better yet, use `while read` loop.

Comment: Why are you using `for `instead of `while read`?

Comment: "I would expect the echo to print each line in the file" You would be wrong then, the result of `\`command\`` is a single line.

Comment: Wow, thanks guys.  So, when does globbing get expanded and when does it not?  Because if I do `echo \`cat $1\``, then it prints the globs (`*.txt`, `*.sh`), and not the files, as expected.  But in the `for` loop it expands the globs.  Why do they both not have the same behavior?

Comment: The comments point out the problem and solution but a broader thing to consider is, for this kind of processing, you're almost always better off just not doing it in shell.

Comment: @n.m.: Not a single line, but a single argument / single string. (unix "line" is precisely defined as a string of non-LF characters followed by LF, and the result of `cat` can certainly include LF).

Comment: ``echo `cat $1` `` does do glob expansion in my shell (`bash`). It appears not to do that in `zsh`; but your question is tagged [tag:bash]...

Comment: @pvg, can you elaborate please?  what is an alternate to using a shell?

Comment: @Hunle I jast added an example to my answer showing how awk could be used in place of the shell loop.  Which tool to use (shell, awk, sed, perl, python, etc.) depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Amadan, you're correct.  I was `echo`ing using double quotes around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the line `` for ftype in `cat $1` ``, the shell performs both *word splitting* and *pathname expansion*.  If you don't want that, use a `while` loop:

```
while read -r ftype
do
    echo "this is ftype $ftype"
done <"$1"
```

This loop reads one line at a time from the file `$1` and, while leading and trailing whitespace are removed from each line, no expansions are performed.
(If you want to keep the leading and trailing whitespace, use `while IFS= read -r ftype`).

Typically, `for` loops are useful when you are looping over items that are already shell-defined variables, like `for x in "$@"`.  If you are reading something in from an external command or file, you typically want a `while read` loop.

#### Alternative not using shell

When processing files line-by-line, the goal can often be accomplished more efficiently using sed or awk.  As an example using awk, the above loop simplifies to:

```
$ awk '{print "this is ftype " $0}' filetypes 
this is ftype *.txt
this is ftype *.sh
```

Comment: Goodly for suggesting the `while x read; do ... done` alternative. Works a lot better on large input!  :-)

Comment: for posterity: http://ccm.net/faq/1757-how-to-read-a-linux-file-line-by-line#simili_main

Comment: @John1024, your solution only prints the first line of the file `file_types` for me, `*.txt` .  Any ideas why?

Comment: @Hunle It prints both lines for me.  My guess is that your file is missing the final newline character.  Bash does not think a line is a line unless it _ends_ with a newline character.  This is the Unix way.  On the other hand, the `awk` solution will print a final line even if it is missing the final newline.

Comment: weird...yeah you're right.  That's annoying but thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $(cat foo)
```

will produce the content of `foo`, split them into words, do globs on each word - i.e. treat the content of `foo` as parameters - before it interpolates it into the current command line.

```
echo "$(cat foo)"
```

will produce the content of `foo` as a single argument, does not treat them as parameters, will not glob (but you will only get one pass through the loop).

You want to read `foo` one line at a time; use `while read -r ftype` for that.